# C++ gives different outputs for almost the same code

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have some lines of a book shuffled and their words are shuffled too. I want to sort them using quicksort algorithm. I sorted the lines and it worked well. then I tried to sort each line like this;

```
for each (Line l in lines) {
    srand(255);
    l.quicksort(0, l.words.size() - 1);
    for each (Word w in l.words)
        cout << w.content << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

srand part is because I am using randomized quick sort. This loop gives me the correct results. However, when I tried to write it again like this;

```
for each (Line l in lines) {
    for each (Word w in l.words)
        cout << w.content << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

It gives an output like I didn't call the quicksort function. It is the same code with one line missing. Why is it happening?

Line class:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include "word.h"
using namespace std;

class Line {
public:
    vector<Word> words;
    Line(string&, string&);
    void quicksort(int, int);
private:
    int partition(int, int);
    void swap(int, int);
};

Line::Line(string& _words, string& orders) {
    // Reading words and orders, it works well.
}

void Line::quicksort(int p, int r) {
    if (p < r) {
        int q = partition(p, r);
        quicksort(p, q - 1);
        quicksort(q + 1, r);
    }
}

int Line::partition(int p, int r) {
    int random = rand() % (r - p + 1) + p;
    swap(r, random);
    int x = words[r].order;
    int i = p - 1;
    for (int j = p; j < r; j++)
        if (words[j].order <= x) {
            i++;
            swap(i, j);
        }
    swap(i + 1, r);
    return i + 1;
}

void Line::swap(int i, int j) {
    if (i != j) {
        Word temp = words[j];
        words[j] = words[i];
        words[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't uderstand, what do you mean by compiler spesific extention? I am using Visual Studio if that is what you mean.

Comment: What are you using rand() on?

Comment: I use rand() for choosing the pivot randomly in each iteration. `x` is pivot here.

Comment: To me this makes no sense: `It gives an output as I didn't call the quicksort function` Of cause it gives an output. Can you elaborate. Also `It is the same code with one line missing` .... then it is not the same code. Please explain.

Comment: `for each (Line l in lines)` - are you sure that is c++ ?

Comment: @4386427 MSVC extension, so technically no, this isn't C++. Recommend a swap for the C++11 range based for: `for (Line & l: lines)` to get standard compliant.

Comment: With @4386427 on the confusion. If you remove the call to quick sort, why would you not expect to get anything but unsorted results?

Comment: But I opened I C++ file in Visual Studio and it gave me this usage of dir each, I just put the variables. Isn't it C++ then? Also I editted my question for clarification.

Comment: I thought when I call it once, it remains sorted since I change the vector inside the object. @user4581301

Comment: So the second code block is after the first code block. It is **not** either the first or the second. Is that it?

Comment: I don't know the `for each` extention as it is not c++. My guess is that `l` becomes a local variable and therefore any change made to it is lost when the loop completes. Try this instead: `for (auto& l : lines)`

Comment: Yes,  the second one comes after the first one. I just called the first two code blocks in the main in that ordet, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Best that I stop at this point and call for a [mcve]. I can't visualize what you are up to. Also watch out. It looks like you're using `using namespace std;` That puts you at risk of `std::swap` being called in place of `Line::swap` and you will get very weird/wrong results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sort a local copy, iterate by reference instead:

```
srand(255); // Call it only once (probably in main)
for (Line& l : lines) {
    l.quicksort(0, l.words.size() - 1);
    for (const Word& w : l.words)
        std::cout << w.content << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
// Second loop
for (const Line& l : lines) {
    for (const Word& w : l.words)
        std::cout << w.content << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```